# Url Routing with Encoding in Java Web API

Tags: java, controller, url-routing, urlencode, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to java and I'm trying to write a utility api to encrypt/decrypt a string. I have my controller and request mapping working, and I have the encrypt/decrypt methods working.

The problem I'm running into is decrypting a string that contains a forward slash ('/'). If I leave it unencoded in the url (such as `http://localhost:8080/api/package/util/decrypt/oJfTtchpM9WC/4Oqpu7FZQ==`) then url routing breaks (which is obvious why).

If I url encode it (such as `http://localhost:8080/api/package/util/decrypt/oJfTtchpM9WC%2F4Oqpu7FZQ==`) then the value in the path variable is empty.

Also note that `http://localhost:8080/api/package/util/decrypt/oJfTtchpM9WC` (no slash) works fine.

It seems whenever I put in a '%' into the path variable, I just get a blank page in response. Doesn't hit the method. Doesn't throw an exception (that I can find - again, I'm learning the environment still)

I've simplified my decrypt method to only output the path variable denoted as `data`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/util/decrypt/{data}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String decrypt(HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
        @PathVariable String data) throws Exception 
{
    return data;
    //    return URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how I can get this working?

Many thanks!!

Comment: is the parameter data null?

Comment: It doesn't even appear to be hitting the decrypt method in the controller.

Comment: did you try passing it as a normal request param ie ?data=yourEncryptedString

Comment: using a request param works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my encrypt method to use the function [encodeBase64URLSafeString](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte%5B%5D%29) (vs just encodeBase64String) and also changed it to pass the data as a standard request param (ie ?data=string). This removed the problem.

> Encodes binary data using a URL-safe variation of the base64 algorithm
>   but does not chunk the output. The url-safe variation emits - and _
>   instead of + and / characters. Note: no padding is added.